# Daily check how many files are ingested in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, bucket

I have a project that will have several video files imported to a certain directory in a certain S3 bucket on a daily basis. That directory will have other folders underneath, so generally speaking, I want to see how many single files in total increased across the folders compared to the day before. I need to show them on a CloudWatch dashboard. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can list all files each day, calculate the difference to the previous day and publish the data as a custom cloudwatch metric.

Comment: Can you tell me how to custom a metric? I didn't find it on the console.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you best bet is to schedule a daily S3 inventory, it'll give you 1 or more CSV files that show the whole bucket. Write a script to compare against the previous day or filter on time stamp.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html